# `npm run build` Stuck at digital ocean when deploying Laravel app with Inertia.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, digital-ocean, inertiajs

I am trying to deploy laravel app with inertia.js (vue) to digital ocean. The deployment was successful, but when I run `npm run build` to compile assets it stuck and just shows:

```
> build
> vue-tsc && vite build && vite build --ssr
```

However, `npm run dev` works fine. What can be wrong and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 1GB RAM helped me with a similar issue.